# Django - UnicodeEncodeError in Production Environment with Apache

Tags: django, apache

I've a Django application in production that is throwing the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 97: ordinal not in range(128)
Unicode error hint
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: P Gen@rica.
```

P Gen@rica is part of the name of an uploaded file.

The code where the error appears is this:

```
files_list = [uuid_temp_files + '/' + f for f in os.listdir(uuid_temp_files) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(uuid_temp_files, f))]
```

In my Development machine everything is OK, I can add accented filenames to the names of files.

Any clues on what the causes of this error in the production environment? Could be some Apache configuration?

Best Regards,

Comment: I assume you're dev machine is using python 3?

Comment: It is using Python2.7

Comment: Why don't you use `os.path.join` on the left-hand side of your list comprehension as well?

Answer (score 3):

Problem corrected with:

```
# CentOS use /etc/sysconfig/httpd to config environment variables.
#
# By default, the httpd process is started in the C locale; to
# change the locale in which the server runs, the LANG
# variable can be set.
#
# LANG=C
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  # you can change to your locale.
```

In the file, "/etc/sysconfig/httpd" change "LANG=C" to "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" then restart Apache.

Done.